JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization using Global default typing for abstract class serialization not writing type info of root kotlin object
I can not use annotation due to restrictions. need some pointers to understand why type information is not getting written to the serialized data when using Global default typing approach of JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization.
I have an abstract class Programme, which also extends some more abstract class up in the hierarchy.
abstract class Programme : Content() {}

and it is extended by a concrete class like
data class Movie (): Programme() {}

using JsonMapper with
activateDefaultTyping(BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build(),
                DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)

serializing using jsonmapper.writeValueAsBytes(value)
I get error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class package.structure.Programme]: missing type id property '@class' I could see that serialized data is not having type info for the Movie object.
at [Source: (byte[])"{"Movie":{"uuid":"some_uuid","localizedMetadata":{"@class":"java.util.LinkedHashMap","en-GB":{"name":"Stray","synopsis":["java.util.ArrayList",[{"type...........[TRIMMED] 
I can see that type info is added as per my config using DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE but type info is not added to the root object Movie
Using jacksonVersion = '2.15.0'
Additionally referred https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3356 , and got a clue that root nodes are not typed, unlike in the example I am not using record object but kotlin data classes. then introduced a wrapper class like below which will hold the entity and serialized the wrapper object.
data class WrapperProgramme<T> (final val programme: T) {}

Also while deserialization instead of payload type, deserialized to Wrapper type and then retrieved actual payload. This lead to move on to next error. I had to add bunch of allowIfBaseType to the BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator
Currently I have below error
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Problem deserializing 'setterless' property ("synopsis"): no way to handle typed deser with setterless yet

I am using Kotlin data classes. Any pointer would help. thanks !
